# How to use Captcha in android form

Tags: android, captcha

1. how to use captcha in android form...
2. how to change captcha picture....
3. how to add captcha library ...

   ```
   public class SampleActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, ReCaptcha.OnShowChallengeListener, ReCaptcha.OnVerifyAnswerListener 
   {
        private static final String PUBLIC_KEY  = "6LcPWugSAAAAAC-MP5sg6wp_CQiyxHvPvkQvVlVf";
        private static final String PRIVATE_KEY = "6LcPWugSAAAAALWMp-gg9QkykQQyO6ePBSUk-Hjg";

        private ReCaptcha   reCaptcha;
        private ProgressBar progress;
        private EditText    answer;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);

            this.reCaptcha = (ReCaptcha)this.findViewById(R.id.recaptcha);
            this.progress  = (ProgressBar)this.findViewById(R.id.progress);
            this.answer    = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.answer);

            this.findViewById(R.id.verify).setOnClickListener(this);
            this.findViewById(R.id.reload).setOnClickListener(this);

            this.showChallenge();
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.verify:
                    this.verifyAnswer();

                    break;

                case R.id.reload:
                    this.showChallenge();

                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChallengeShown(final boolean shown) {
            this.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (shown) {
                // If a CAPTCHA is shown successfully, displays it for the user to enter the words
                this.reCaptcha.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.show_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnswerVerified(final boolean success) {
            if (success) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.verification_success, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.verification_failed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            // (Optional) Shows the next CAPTCHA
            this.showChallenge();
        }

        private void showChallenge() {
            // Displays a progress bar while downloading CAPTCHA
            this.progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            this.reCaptcha.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            this.reCaptcha.showChallengeAsync(SampleActivity.PUBLIC_KEY, this);
        }

        private void verifyAnswer() {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(this.answer.getText())) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.instruction, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // Displays a progress bar while submitting the answer for verification
                this.progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                this.reCaptcha.verifyAnswerAsync(SampleActivity.PRIVATE_KEY, this.answer.getText().toString(), this);
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an implemented library which you can use as example.

https://github.com/ayltai/Android-Lib-reCAPTCHA